# Impacts of matricentric reproductive laws

Tags: society, economy, culture, near-future, social-norms

My world is a matricentric America that holds men legally responsible for unplanned pregnancies. Roughly, the idea is that if an unplanned pregnancy occurs and the woman ***does* *not*** get an abortion, the man who's sperm was responsible can either pay a large lump sum of money (enough to support the child and mother until adulthood) *or* can essentially become an indentured servant to the child and the mother until the child reaches adulthood, i.e. must fulfill all domestic duties and affective labor. If the woman ***does*** get an abortion, the man is responsible for all medical bills, and must additionally pay a smaller fine to the woman for pain and suffering.

I am including things like how this would affect different and unexpected aspects of culture, such as the impact this would have on the porn culture, cultural beauty standards, and how the pharmaceutical industry would change their areas of research.

What I am tossing back and forth is this: Would the welfare system (government benefits) still exist?

Maybe this is too broad of a question - I'm just trying to fully flesh out the cultural construct of this concept, and looking for some fresh perspectives.

Comment: Interesting and provocative worldbuilding! Good luck in fleshing it out. But for the scope of asking questions on this site, the idea is to go specific, not broad. As it's currently written, this question is probably not a good match for the site, and might be at risk of being closed. Could you perhaps break it down into multiple questions, each related to a specific aspect/element of the society you're working on? Or perhaps ask on the sandbox question in the meta site?

Comment: what if they change their mind about the indentured servitude? Can they switch to a prorated payment? Also, making it a lump sum seems like it might incentivize some people to get pregnant for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Ignorant foreigner here. Should I understand that in real-life USA the man who made the mother pregnant is *not* responsible for the maintenance of the child? Because in Europe he surely is.

Comment: Alex: theoretically he is, but in practice the man is only held responsible if the mother can afford a better lawyer, or if he can't afford one at all.

Comment: @AlexP The only way's to get out of child support in the USA as far as I know are:
1) child is older then 18/or graduates from highschool
2) Child isn't yours and you spend a lot of money/time proving it.
3) you get back together. 
1/3 are much easier then 2. Unlike what has been previously stated, It doesn't matter how much better your lawyer is then theirs, unless number 2 applies. And then your lawyer has to be a lot of a lot better. How much you pay can be effeected by lawyer quality... But you will pay it.

Comment: A lump-sum payment is probably not going to pass muster with the courts for a variety of reasons from the obvious (what if the man doesn't *have* that much?) to the domain-specific (a lump sum of cash could be bad news vis-a-vis needs-based welfare). As cowlinator points out, it also gives a bit of a perverse incentive to get pregnant. (What happens to the kid in that case is perhaps better left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: VTC: (a) This is an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). (b) Even the culture of a small town would be too broad for a question like this. Individual reactions will vary based on their politics, religion, education, social influences, etc., etc., etc. (c) No national law like this can exist (Constitution: rights not explicitly reserved to federal govt revert to the state or people), which means you have 50 state interpretations.

Comment: Also, the welfare system exists for a great many more reasons than just unwed mothers. Frankly, while the idea is interesting, it's not well fleshed out. Must the father continue to pay if the mother marries? How about if she shacks up with someone who can financially care for her? What if she wins the lottery? What about mothers who want nothing to do with the father? What if they're married but the father is unemployed? All laws are a lot more complex than you're suggesting.

Comment: Your question seems an attempt of brainstorming, which we don't do here, and the final question doesn't derives from its premises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to answer the narrow part of your question:

> What I am tossing back and forth is this: Would the welfare system (government benefits) still exist?

Yes.

1. Someone needs to enforce the collection of payments and/or indenturing of responsible men.
2. Financial support for unmarried women with children is a minority of government benefits in the USA, let alone any other country.
3. Sometimes the responsible man will be unable to supply either labor or money -- if he's dead, for example.

Answer (score 2):

1. Less sex out of marriage, at least for men,  You've increased the risk of sex for men so naturally you decreased  The amount of men willing to have sex without some sort of social safety net like marriage.
2. A lot more paternity suits, Considering the  cost  Of having a child out of wedlock, Expect more men take  It to court to try and prove that they are not the father.
3. More babies born out of Wedlock,  You're  Essentially incentivine woman to have children Out of wedlock with wealthier men.   Considering having child out of wedlock equals either,  Being financially set for life, Or receiving your personal slave, This gives a lot of incentives  for women  Is to pursue having as many kids with as many wealthy menace possible. You would see an increase of single mothers with large families.